# Dx Extreme Html5 grid loading panel wont disappear after grouping

Tags: devexpress, devextreme

I have a grid with server side sorting and paging enabled, but client side grouping.  The onOptionChanged event calls a function which gets new data into a custom store, it all works great.  Trouble is, I have client side grouping enabled, this also calls the function, however the loading panel never goes away after grouping.  I have tried actively turning off the loading panel if the event is grouping, eg

```
  if (e.fullName.indexOf("groupIndex") > -1) {
               // $(".dx-loadpanel").hide();
                e.component.endCustomLoading();
                return false;
            }
```

but this doesn't work, ie, it doesn't hide the loading panel.  If I toggle the display (commented code above) this hides the loading panel for all subsequent operations which is not great.

How do I only show loading panel if a server side operation, but not client side?

Thanks,

Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, grouping doesn't populate take and skip params